# RISC V Assembly Program: Unable to load the floating point register f0,f1 with the floating point instructions .Why the value is not getting loaded?

Tags: riscv

### Code to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

- Input 100.0f Stored in the x8 integer register.
- Output in the f0 register.

What is the error in the code?

Trying to implement the formula: Output = (100.0-32.0)*(5.0/9.0)

```
_start:
li x5,0x40a00000    # floating point representation of 5 in hex as per IEEE 754 notation. Storing in x5.
li x6, 0x41100000   # floating point representation of 9 in hex as per IEEE 754 notation. Storing in x6.
li x7, 0x42000000   # floating point representation of 32 in hex as per IEEE 754 notation. Storing in x7.
li x8, 0x42c80000   # floating point representation of 100 in hex as per IEEE 754 notation. Storing in x8. This is the input.
flw f0,0(x5)        # Storing the value 5.0 in the floating point register f0
flw f1,0(x6)        # Storing the value 9.0 in the floating point register f1
flw f2,0(x8)        # Storing the value 100.0 in the floating point register f2
fdiv.s f0, f0, f1   # storing the value 5.0/9.0 in the register f0
flw f1, 0(x7)       # storing the value 32.0 in the register f1.
fsub.s f2, f2, f1   # f2 = 100.0f – 32.0f = 68.0f
fmul.s f0, f0, f2   # f0 =  68.0f*(5.0f/9.0f) This is the output.
```

#### Compile Command:

```
~/spiking$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T spike.lds faren.S -o faren.elf**
```

[image: Screenshot of gdb debugger]

Comment: Hello! Can you please tell me how you run your risc-v program in Ubuntu?
I'm trying to do so. Does it run in a virtual machine (e.g. Qemu)?
I need the details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `flw` instruction is used to load a floating-point value from memory. In your case, you use `x5` as a pointer (which isn't what you intended).

To move the bits untouched from an X register to a floating-point register you can use `fmv.w.x`.